# Performance with autoload and the options table

Tags: database, options, cache, table

I am playing around with the `autoload` column of the `options` table. I didn't find much information about how the autoloaded values are used. I tried a `print_r($GLOBALS)` and saw that the autoloaded options are stored in `$GLOBALS['wp_object_cache']->cache['options']['alloptions']`.

Is there another way to access those variables?

Suppose I need to access an option `my_option`, which was set to autoload, multiple times in different templates (eg. once in `header.php`, once in `footer.php`), which method is recommended?

1. Is it okay that I retrieve it from the `$GLOBALS` array(since the value is already here)
2. Must I use `get_option('my_option')` once and globalize the variable **again**
3. Use `get_option('my_option')` each time (which I don't see the point of doing)
4. Something else

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> I didn't find much information about how the autoloaded values are
>   used.

There is no special case for autoloaded options, they are used in the same way as else regular options, but lets figure out what `autoload` column of the `options` table means. This column determines do we need to fetch an option at the initialization stage of a request or should we fetch an option only on demand.

But when this autoloading happens and what function does it? All *autoload* options are loaded and cached by `wp_load_alloptions` function, which is called by `is_blog_installed` function at the beginning of each HTTP request, handled by WP.

Lets summarize: autoloaded option is the same option, but loaded at the beginning of HTTP request processing by WP.

> Suppose I need to access an option ... which method is recommended?

1. It is bad approach to retrieve it from `$GLOBALS` directly, use `get_option` instead
2. Globalize custom variables is not welcome and recommended to do it as less as possible
3. From my point of view it's the best option for you
4. Even don't think about something else :)

Why to use `get_option` function each time is the best option? Because:

1. The first and the most important *because*: you can be confident that it will return up-to-date value, each time you call it.
2. It will cache it for future reuse.
3. It allows other plugin and theme to hook your option by hooking `option_optionname` filter.
4. It will fetch an option if it is not loaded yet.

Comment: +1 very informative answer. Never heard about the option hook before :)

Comment: @rrikesh u r welcome, hope it explains good enough