# Can set_transient() be used in multi-site?

Tags: multisite, transient

I understand that [Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) is used to cache data and should be intended to store data that is expected to expire.

**However, please clarify the following.**

Can `set_transient()` be used to store data in multi-site scenario? If yes, how is it different from  using `set_site_transient()` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_site_transient) suggests:

> Essentially the same as set_transient() but works network wide when
> using WP Multisite.
>
> One difference is that the transient name should be 40 characters or
> less in length. Also, while set_transient() sets transients that have
> an expiration time to not autoload, all transients added with
> `set_site_transient` **will auto-load at all times**.

In other words, the fundamental difference is in the [auto-loading](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/83776/98010) and since transients might be serialized, you could risk breaking things if referring to a blog (in MU) which has different settings/url/etc.

**So the short answer is:**

- use set_transient for single blogs
- use set_site_transient when you need something for ALL blogs.

Example of stored transients:

[image]

Comment: From your answer, I understand the following.

1. We can use `set_transient` for multisite
2. If we have blog specific data to be stored in cache, then it is better to use `set_site_transient`.

Could you let me know if I get it right?

Comment: **1.** Yes, you can use it with WP MU. **2.** If for _blog_ you mean the whole WP Multisite, then yes. `set_site_transient` is meant to work on a more global level, while `set_transient` on a single blog level.